# Does Elasticsearch Support TTL for Index Aliases?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

Does Elasticsearch Support TTL for Index Aliases?

Alternatively, is there a way to auto remove an Index Aliase without affecting the master index?

Answer (score 0):

No, Elastic doesn't support TTL for index aliases. Once an alias is set it's there to stay. However, nothing prevents you from setting up a cron job that will remove the alias from a given index or set of indexes.